# no output on gettxout method [All Blocks Are Counted]

Tags: litecoin, full-node, nodes

`litecoin-cli gettxout "9d56b3bf179a988873fc2162d70bba44849ef822764c9049a0f722b5fdc9acc1" 1`

This is the command im using to get information about a transaction.

`litecoind -txindex=1 -daemon -conf=/home/litecoin/.litecoin/litecoin.conf -reindex -rpcuser=cryptosensei -rpcpassword=foo_420 -rpcport=9332 -rpcthreads=1000`

This is the command i use for starting up my daemon. with the `-reindex` it should not re-verify the blocks. So im wondering why im getting null.

If anyone knows what the issue let me know. Also here is the response of `getnetworkinfo` & `getblockcount`

**getblockcount**

```
litecoin@Debian-913-stretch-64-minimal:/root$ litecoin-cli getblockcount
0
```

**getblockchaininfo**

```
litecoin@Debian-913-stretch-64-minimal:/root$ litecoin-cli getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 0,
  "headers": 526188,
  "bestblockhash": "12a765e31ffd4059bada1e25190f6e98c99d9714d334efa41a195a7e7e04bfe2",
  "difficulty": 0.000244140625,
  "mediantime": 1317972665,
  "verificationprogress": 1.737314343731834e-08,
  "initialblockdownload": true,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010",
  "size_on_disk": 2217395400,
  "pruned": false,
  "softforks": [
    {
      "id": "bip34",
      "version": 2,
      "reject": {
        "status": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip66",
      "version": 3,
      "reject": {
        "status": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip65",
      "version": 4,
      "reject": {
        "status": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "csv": {
      "status": "defined",
      "startTime": 1485561600,
      "timeout": 1517356801,
      "since": 0
    },
    "segwit": {
      "status": "defined",
      "startTime": 1485561600,
      "timeout": 1517356801,
      "since": 0
    }
  },
  "warnings": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is identical to Bitcoin Core.

This is somewhat confusing, but it simply means that UTXO is spent. It is reporting "nothing" as output.

Comment: Yep very confusing. Also yes it is completly identical to bitcoin core actually. What im asking myself is what the exact difference between `-reindex` & `-reindex-chainstate` is. Maybe this is the cause of all of that

Comment: -reindex scans all block data again; -reindex-chainstate assumes your blocks are fine. It sounds unrelated to your question - there is nothing wrong here. The output you're asking about simply has been spent already.

Comment: Ahh okay. So what method is the correct one to simply check a transaction? [Confirmations etc]

Comment: gettransaction (only works for transactions in your own wallet), or getrawtransaction (for all transactions, but only works if you have txindex enabled).

Comment: `gettransaction` returns that its a non found method for some reason. Yet i have the txindex enabled and set but it won't work for me for some reason. You see that in my parameters to start the node i have `txindex=1`

Comment: As I said, `gettransaction` is only for transactions in your own wallet. If you want to query for other ones, use `getrawtransaction`.

Comment: But -txindex=1 is legitimate in the start parameters right? Also is that true that i need to have the -reindex parameter to have -txindex=1 fully functional? I read thats what common explorers use

Comment: Since Bitcoin Core v0.17 there is no need to reindex anymore when you enable txindex; the missing part gets rebuilt automatically. Block explorers in general don't use Bitcoin Core (or at least not solely; they use additional software to build an index of blocks/transactions).

Comment: I see, yes this is for a school project anyways. But so im right that with an older version `-reindex` is needed? Also just to be sure. To use `-txindex=1` is correct in the start parameters and not something like `-txindex 1`

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. Generally you'd put `txindex=1` in your bitcoin.conf file, because you want it to always be enabled. The reindexing is something you want to only do once (so it should not go in bitcoin.conf; if it does, it'll rebuild the entire database from scratch every time you restart Bitcoin Core).

Comment: Thank you very much. So if reindex is only used once. When is the appropriate time? The first time running the node?

Comment: It's only needed if you previously had a node running without `txindex=1`, and want to enable it. It is needed because (before Bitcoin Core 0.17) it couldn't build the txindex on the fly; you had to start over. If you run with `txindex=1` the first time you run Bitcoin Core, no reindex is needed.

Comment: Perfect. So i won't need -reindex if i will re-install the node from scratch right. Also do you recommend the `-reindex-chainstate` parameter if the node server ever crashes. Also thank you very much for your information. It's an honour to me to get informations from a bitcoin-core contributor :)